Find the probability distribution density of a random process at the output of a nonlinear circuit
I know:

Probability distribution density at the input of the circuit
$$
    W(x) = \frac{\mu}{2\left(1+\mu^2\left(x-m\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$
Non-linear function
$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1 \cdot x - x
$$

It is necessary to find: the density of the probability distribution at the output of the circuit.
$$
W(y) = ?
$$
To do this, a nonlinear transformation must be applied.

To do this, a nonlinear transformation must be applied.
Since the process undergoes a nonlinear transformation, the probability density undergoes the same transformation.
Let's choose some value $x$, this value uniquely corresponds to the value $y$ of the output process.  Let's give the value of $x$ an elementary increment. This increment will correspond to the elementary increment of the output process $y$.
Since the dependence $f(x)$ is unambiguous, the probability that the value of the random variable $Y$ will be within $(y, y+\Delta y)$ should be equal to the probability that the random variable $X$ will be within $(x, x+\Delta x)$ , that is
$$
p(y\leq Y \leq y + \Delta y) = p(x\leq X \leq x + \Delta x) 
$$
or
$$
W(y) dy = W(x) dx
$$
from where it follows:
$$
W(y) = W(x) \left| \frac{dx}{dy}  \right|
$$
$$
W(y) = W(\phi(y)) \left| \frac{d\phi(y)}{dy}  \right|
$$
where $\phi(y) = f(x)$ the inverse function $f(x)$:
$$\phi(y) = \frac{y-a_0}{1+a_1}$$
Let's find the derivative of the inverse function:
$$\frac{d}{dy}\phi(y) = \frac{1}{1+a_1}$$
then
$$
W(y) = \frac{\mu}{2\left(1+\mu^2\left(\frac{y-a_0}{1+a_1}-m\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}\cdot \left| \frac{1}{1+a_1}  \right|
$$
Did I understand the essence of the nonlinear transformation of a random process correctly?

The pdf of $a_0+(a_1-1)X$ is given by
$$f_{a_0+(a_1-1)X}(y) = \frac{\mu}{2\left(1+\mu^2\left(\frac{y-a_0}{a_1\color{red}{-}1}-m\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}\cdot \left| \frac{1}{a_1\color{red}{-}1}  \right|
.$$
It follows from the general formula:
$$f_{a+bX}(y)=\frac{1}{|b|}f_{X}\left(\frac{y-a}{b} \right).$$
